# New html,css,js page for each user/product

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am relatively new to web development, I was just thinking whether Facebook/twitter or Amazon make a new html,css,js page for each user/product. If not, is it possible to replicate this action using the tech i am learning.

HTML, CSS, JavaScript + React, Node.js and MongoDB

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: sort-of! I'll use Facebook as an example.

Facebook has roughly 2 billion users. Each user can go to their profile page. But Facebook does *not* have 2 billion "profile.html" pages stored on its server. There would be many problems with that:

- That would be a tremendous amount of data to store.
- Profile pages all have a lot in common: they have the same color/font theme, the same general layout, the same headers and footers... Storing 2 billion files that are very similar is not an efficient use of space.
- Let's say Facebook wanted to change the font on the profile page. They would need to update all 2 billion profile pages, which is not efficient.

Instead, Facebook stores one **template** of a profile page. Then, when User Alice goes to her profile, Facebook loads the template, loads Alice's data from a database, inserts her data into the template, and *then* sends Alice that filled-out template.

That way, Facebook gets these advantages:

- They store a much smaller amount of data
- If they want to change the font of the profile page, they only need to change the template

All of the other platforms aside from Facebook do this same thing.

Comment: You're welcome, @Pierre. If this answer is helpful, please click the checkmark to mark it as "accepted".